# Can't access object property on a React object state, even though it exists. Returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using AJAX to get some JSON, and then I want to display the value.  If I log out he object that contains the value I want to display, I can see the key and the value.  However, when I try to access the value directly, I get undefined.

Here is the component that I am stuck on:

```
var WeatherCard = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var comp = this;
    $.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" +  this.props.zipcode + ",us", function(data) {
    comp.setState(data);
  });
 },
 render: function() {
    // I want to get the value @ this.state.main.temp

    // this works...
    console.log(this.state.main);

    // this does not work...
    // console.log(this.state.main.temp);

    // I want "current temp" to display this.state.main.temp
    return (
        <div className="well">
          <h3>{this.state.name}</h3>
          <p>Current Temp: {this.state.main} </p>
          <p>Zipcode: {this.props.zipcode}</p>
        </div>
     );
    }
});
```

Here is the whole plunk.
http://plnkr.co/edit/oo0RgYOzvitDiEw5UuS8?p=info

Answer (score 6):

On first pass, `this.state` is empty which will render `this.state.main.temp` as undefined. Either you prefill the state with a correct structured object or wrap in `if` clauses.

For objects that returns null or undefined React will simply skip rendering it without any warnings or errors, however when you have nested structures that return null or undefined normal JavaScript behaviour is employed.

Comment: To initialize the state, one should use [`getInitialState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

Comment: I know, just wanted to say, that the user should've used it further to initialize `main.temp`

Comment: When you say wrap in if clauses, do you mean the return in the render method?  I've tried to find the react 'best practice" for this but no luck so far.  I don't want to pre-fill the state because initializing all the values would be a mass of JOSN in my component, and just initializing the main.temp value would be an issue later if I want to render more data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your initial state using main: [], data: [] rather than an empty object.

I was having the same problems and once I took my AJAX setState and made an empty initial state everything started working fine.

I'm new to React so I can't give you a very good explanation as to why this made a difference. I seem to stumble into all kinds of strange problems.

Hope this helped.